# 2 primefaces captchas in one page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, captcha

I am currently using primefaces5.0 and jsf2.2. I am doing a tab view such that I will have two captchas in each of the tab, but it seems like i am only allowed to have one captcha in a page, as only one captcha appears on one tab.

[image: tab with captcha]

[image]

How do i make it such that i have 2 captcha on these two tabs? These is my code for the captchas.

```
 <p:captcha id="captcha1" label="Captcha1" secure="true"/>
 <p:captcha id="captcha12" label="Captcha2" secure="true"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.A variable on the session holds the current state of the captcha which would take only one. The main point of the captcha is to identify if the user is human being.. why would you have it twice in one form ?. I can see one solution.. you might use jQuery clone but in this case you would have two in one.. so if the user had the first tab wrong the second would be identical!

Comment: so how do I do that using jquery clone? i cloned it when i onclick mobile tab?

Comment: you just define a div with an id, and on document ready you clone the original one into that div in the other tab.